# How to update widget from another application?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, homescreen, onupdate

I have made an `application` and a `widget`. I have to update my `widget` from the application i.e. send some data to the widget. I used the `sendBroadcast(Intent intent)` method from the application. It is well received in the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method of MyWidgetProvider app. I am able to get the data, But the `onUpdate()` method does not seem to work and hence no UI for the widget.

this is the code for widget app

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public String team1name;
    public String team2name;
    public String team1score;
    public String team2score;    
    public static boolean done=false;

        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
              return;
            }
            team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
            team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
            team1score = extras.getString("team1score");
            team2score = extras.getString("team2score");    
            done=true;
        }

        private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

          @Override
          public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

            // Get all ids
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);
            int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
            for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
                Log.e("WidgetExample", "The victory is mine");

              RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
              // Set the text
              remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, team1name);

              // Register an onClickListener
              Intent i = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

              i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
              i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

              PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
              remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
              appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
            }
          }
```

Comment: please add your `onReceive()` method.

Comment: @hasanghaforian I solved the above question myself. Below is my answer. However, I am stuck on this question, Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346285/how-to-get-to-another-application-on-click-of-a-widget

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }

    team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
    team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
    team1score = extras.getString("team1score");
    team2score = extras.getString("team2score");    
    done = true;
}
```

You are supposed to call `onUpdate` from `onReceive`. Receiving the broadcast won't just make the `AppWidgetProvider` call onUpdate by itself. You need to do that manually.

Comment: Widget update seems to be working now. Please see my answer. Also, Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346285/how-to-get-to-another-application-on-click-of-a-widget

Answer (score 0):

I had to make use of RemoteViews in the onReceive method itself. This worked for me.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }

    team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
    team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
    team1score = extras.getString("team1score");
    team2score = extras.getString("team2score");
    player1 = extras.getString("player1");
    player2 = extras.getString("player2");
    extras = null;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1name, team1name);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2name, team2name);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.teamscore, team2score);  
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batsman1, player1);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.bowler, player2);

    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, remoteViews);
}
```