# How to get to another application on click of a widget

Tags: android, widget

I want to get to another application when I click my `widget`. It doesn't seem to be working. Please tell me where I am going wrong. 
Here's my code so far.

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public String team1name;
    public String team2name;
    public String team1score;
    public String team2score;
          @Override
            public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
                super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
                Log.i(MyWidgetProvider.class.toString(), "Onupdate called for " + this);

                  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName (), R.layout.widget_layout); 

                  Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                  PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                  in = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.playup.android.adapters");
                  in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0 /* no requestCode */, in, 0 /* no flags */);
                  remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pendingIntent2);

                  ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
                  AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                  manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
            }
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras == null) {
                  return;
                }
                team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
                team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
                team1score = extras.getString("team1score");
                team2score = extras.getString("team2score");    


                    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1name, team1name);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2name, team2name);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1score, team1score);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2score, team2score);

                        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);  
                        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, remoteViews);
            }
}
```

Comment: @iturki I edited it. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you set your layout's or component's id as layout, where you added that click listener. Cause i have executed your code it works fine except if that package named app is not installed widget crashes, but i think this is not happening  in your case.

Comment: widget does not crash, the package is installed

Answer (score 0):

I simply added some code from onUpdate() method to onReceive() method and it worked.
This is the code.

```
      Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
      in = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.playup.android.adapters");
      in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0 /* no requestCode */, in, 0 /* no flags */);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pendingIntent2);
```